# Finding partial derivatives for 4 x-y functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This question is in 4 parts **(a)** to **(d)**. For each function $f(x,y)$, I am asked to find $f'_x(x,y)$ and $f'_y(x,y)$.

**(a)**

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= x^2 +2xy + y^2
\\f'_x(x,y) &= 2x+2y
\\f'_y(x,y) &= 2x + 2y
\end{align*}
$$

**(b)**

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= x^3e^{-y} + y^3
\\f'_x(x,y) &= 3x^2e^{-y}
\\f'_y(x,y) &= -x^3e^{-y} +3y^2
\end{align*}
$$

**(c)**

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= x^2ye^{xy}
\\f'_x(x,y) &= 2xye^{xy} + x^2y^2e^{xy}
\\f'_y(x,y) &= x^2e^{xy}+ y^2x^2e^{xy}
\end{align*}
$$
**(d)**

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= \frac{x^2y^3}{\sqrt{x+y}}
\\f'_x(x,y) &= \frac{\sqrt{x+y} \times 2xy^3 - \frac{x^2y^3}{2\sqrt{x+y}}}{x+y}
\\&= \frac{2xy^3(x+y) - \frac{x^2y^3}{2}}{(x+y)\sqrt{x+y}}
\\f'_y(x,y) &= \frac{\sqrt{x+y} \times 3x^2y^2 - \frac{x^2y^3}{2\sqrt{x+y}}}{x+y}
\\&= \frac{ 3x^2y^2(x+y) - \frac{x^2y^3}{2}}{(x+y)\sqrt{x+y}}
\end{align*}
$$

I am especially uncomfortable with **(c)** and **(d)**. Could somebody help to check my working?

Comment: Is this a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you wanted to multiply by $\sqrt{x+y}$ not only numerator but also denominator (while calculating derivatives in d)). Also, second component of $f_y'$ in c) is incorrect. It should be equal to $y\cdot (x^2e^{xy})_y'=yx^3e^{xy}$. I cannot see any other mistakes.